# It is not possible to edit a tag Wiki, nor create one

Tags: support, tags

I was trying to add a Wiki page to a tag here on meta, but I have problems to create it: when I click on the button to create it, nothing happens.
I also tried to edit an existing tag Wiki, but again I could not do that. Clicking on the edit link that appears in the pop up associated with a tag takes me, e.g., to https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/discussion/info, where I see the "Edit Tag Wiki" button; when I click on that button, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We aren't supporting tag wikis on per-site (child) metas right now -- we plan to push across all the standard meta tag wikis from meta.so regularly.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking "propose tag wiki" doesn't work on this meta site for me either. I've got the "tag editor" badge on the main site, so I *can* make some entries with my sad level of karma/rep.